# EXACT INDSET is DP-complete

Tags: np-complete, np, complexity-classes, induction, co-np

The class DP is defined as the set of languages L for which there are
two languages $L1 \in NP$ , $L2 \in coNP$ such that $L = L1 \cap L2$. (Do not
confuse DP with $NP \cap coNP$, which may seem superficially similar.)
Show that

(a) EXACT INDSET ∈ DP.

(b) Every language in DP is polynomial-time reducible to EXACT INDSET.

[Exercise 8, page 12](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Ereif/courses/complectures/books/AB/phchap.pdf)

Clarifications: EXACT INDSET = {<G, k> : the largest independent set in G has size exactly k}.

Thoughts: I know that INDSET is NP-COMPLETE.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that $\texttt{EXACT INDSET} = \texttt{INDSET}\cap L$ with: $$L = \{\langle G, k\rangle \mid G \text{ has no independent set of size }\geqslant k + 1\}$$ and show that $L$ is $\text{co}\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

Comment: can you help me a bit with proving that L  is coNP-complete?